# How to print multiply sheets with selected page range into single PDF file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export-to-pdf

I have a workbook with 8 sheets and I planned to export all of them into single PDF file, but some sheets consist of only one page, and some of them have 2 or 3 pages to print. How to write it by using VBA? I tried to figure out some idea but all examples explained situation where multiple sheets is printed without taking in account number of pages on each sheets, is it possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have controlled each Sheet, from Sheet1...Sheet8 thru menu option View -> Page Break View, where I adjusted by mouse print margins on right and lower side. Then plain routine printed it well, without hassle:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2",... "Sheet8")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\my_workbook.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

and it works, for now. I don't know is there some dependency of Excel version (2000 - 2013), because i can't check it. Thanks to all for visit and help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the entire workbook and all pages within to a single pdf, try:

```
Sub Print_Workbook()
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "[C:\your_filename_here].pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have implemented similar solution but doesn't work for me as I planned and described it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Tested and working.

```
Sub SaveToPDF()

'This is where we will save the file to a PDF
   Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
   "insert file path here\insertfilename.pdf", _
   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't match my needs; as I said, my workbook consist of 8 sheets, but I want to print particular pages of each sheets, not as much as there exist pages, for example I need to print:
sheet1; 1 and 2 pages
sheet2; 1,2 and 3 pages
sheet3; 1 page
...
sheet8; only 1 page
Thanks to all for your effort to help